# Sort associative arrays in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've a big problem. I want to sort an array like this:

```
 '0' ...
        '0' ...
            'id' => "XXXXX"
            'from' ...
                'name' => "XXXX"
                'id' => "XXXXXXXX"
            'story' => "XXXXXXXXXX"
        '1' ...
            'id' => "XXXXX"
            'from' ...
                'name' => "XXXX"
                'id' => "XXXXXXXX"
            'story' => "XXXXXXXXXX"
        '2' ...
            'id' => "XXXXX"
            'from' ...
                'name' => "XXXX"
                'id' => "XXXXXXXX"
            'story' => "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

I'd like to sort array by key FROM-NAME.
Can you help me?

Comment: Just a point on terminology: you are not sorting an associative array, you are sorting an array of objects.  Associative arrays (objects in JS) have no order so they can't be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourarray.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.from.name<b.from.name ? -1 : 1;
});
```